# How to skip a file in IVsSingleFileGenerator?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vs-extensibility, visual-studio-sdk

I have CustomTool and implementation for IVsSingleFileGenerator. 
How can I skip a file for generation and keep the current version of output content (prevent regeneration)?

```
int IVsSingleFileGenerator.Generate(string wszInputFilePath, string bstrInputFileContents, string wszDefaultNamespace, IntPtr[] rgbOutputFileContents, out uint pcbOutput, IVsGeneratorProgress pGenerateProgress)
{
   if(some_expression)
       // Skip this file from generate and keep the current version
}
```

When I return pcbOutput = 0, output file is cleared.

Comment: What happens if you return `VSConstants.E_FAIL` instead of `VSConstants.S_OK`? The other thing I'd try is returning `VSConstants.S_FALSE`.

Comment: @280Z28 If I return `S_OK` or  `S_FALSE`, generator clears output file, because output param is 0. When I return `E_FAIL`, generator removes output file.

Answer (score 0):

Read the existing contents of the output file.  Then stuff them back into pcbOutput

```
public int Generate(string wszInputFilePath, string bstrInputFileContents, string wszDefaultNamespace, IntPtr[] rgbOutputFileContents, out uint pcbOutput, IVsGeneratorProgress pGenerateProgress)
{
    var originalFileName = GetOriginalFileName(wszInputFilePath);
    SaveOutputContent(rgbOutputFileContents, out pcbOutput, system.IO.File.ReadAllText(originalFileName));
    return VSConstants.S_OK;
}
```

You have to write the code for GetOriginalFileName